# C# Pinning pixel data of custom object

Tags: c#, unsafe, pinning

I have two IntPtr's to two different float images (source.IP and destination.IP).

I copy a block of pixels from one image to the other.

```
int j = 0;
for (int y0 = y; y0 < h + y; y0++)
{
    float* s = ((float*)source.IP) + (y0 * sourcewidth) + x;
    float* d = ((float*)destination.IP) + ((ydestination + j) * destinationwidth) + xdestination;

    for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
    {
        *d = *s;
        s++;
        d++;
    }

    j++;
}
```

The above code is running in an unsafe block.

The question is: **How do I pin the image data while copying so that the GC doesn't move it around?**

If I use GCHandle.Alloc(source) I get: *ArgumentException:  Object contains non-primitive or non-blittable data error.*

**EDIT**

The reason for using unsafe code is because the only access to the image data is through the IntPtr source.IP, if there is another way to copy the data I am open minded :)

Comment: What is the reason for using unsafe programming?

Comment: A thirdparty is delivering the source and destination objects. The only access to the pixels is using the IntPtr's. Is there a better way?